# Screen Capturing with Javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, webrtc

I found http://www.rtcmulticonnection.org/docs/ – apparently, it is possible to share one's screen with another user over WebRTC. Now, WebRTC is certainly nice for real-time-sharing, but I wonder, is it possible by pure JavaScript to take (with the User's permission) Screenshots and process them directly (for example to send them via usual HTTP)? This would be a nice feature for helping people out remotely, without them having to install a VNC/RDP/NX server (but when it's not so important to have a real-time connection, but rather have a reliable transport).
**As I stated, I really mean screenshots, not just recording of the active tab.**

Ok, to be more clear, the problem is that apparently it is possible to tell the browser to do screen sharing via WebRTC (or ask the user whether or not to do so). But it is not (directly) possible to programmatically access the screen once the permission has been given, at least not as far as I see so far.

For the record: https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder does what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many solutions:

1) You can use **[RecordRTC](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-captureVisibleTab)** or similar solutions (e.g. **[MediaStreamRecorder](https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder)** etc.) to record an interval of screen and upload "recorded-screen" to server

2) You can use `<canvas>` (2D) to take snapshot of screen and upload to server using realtime protocols e.g. websockets or XHR-long-polling or simple XMLHttpRequest

3) To support non-WebRTC browsers, you can use solutions similar to [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) that supports webpage's snapshot capturing through Canvas2D API

4) If you're planning to write chrome extension, then you may wanna use "[captureVisibleTab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-captureVisibleTab)" API.

PS. You can take snapshot of the screen using this method:

```
function takeSnapshot(video) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = video.videoWidth || video.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = video.videoHeight || video.clientHeight;

    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    return canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
}
```

Here is how to use it:

```
var screenVideo = document.querySelector('video');
var screenShot = takeSnapshot(screenVideo);
socketio.emit('screenshot', screenShot); // POST to server
```

Comment: This "answer" is NOT targeting how to "CAPTURE" screen. It merely explains how to take snapshot of the screen so that you can UPLOAD that snapshot to server.

Comment: You could also establish an RTCDataChannel and send the images as files across that, to avoid the need to proxy the images through a server.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I have not been clear enough in my question. I Edited it. Specifically your "html2canvas" solution is not feasible. @xdumaine how can I make RTCDataChannel use normal HTTP?

Comment: Ok. MediaStreamRecorder appears to do what I want.

Comment: @schoppenhauer You can capture full-screen using [this open-sourced chrome extension](https://github.com/muaz-khan/Chrome-Extensions/tree/master/desktopCapture) and, then you should preview captured screen in a `<video>` tag and, now you can use above code snippet to take the screenshot(s). You can check [Firefox screen-capturing addon](https://github.com/muaz-khan/Firefox-Extensions/tree/master/enable-screen-capturing) as well.